# Can Keylogger apps able to see the messages sent via SendMessage()?

Tags: c#, windows, keylogger

I am creating a c# app to send a message in a notepad using the SendMessage() function. I have successfuly passed the strings to notepad. The strings are very important and i was wondering if a keylogger program can see this message?

If yes, do you have any other ideas on how i can send the strings securely?

Below is a sample code i used.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string   lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);


    Process[] notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
    if (notepads.Length == 0) return;
    if (notepads[0] != null)
    {
        IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepads[0].MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
        SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, TextBox1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: I think Keyloggers record the key strikes in the keyboard, so there should not be recordings of messages sent using the SendMessage function because no one is actually pressing the keyboard, it depends on the source of those messages that you're sending to the notepad

Comment: @juanreyesv Depends on whether you're referring to a physical (hardware) keylogger or a software keylogger. A software keylogger would probably have a `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook installed, so it would pick up virtual keystrokes as well as physical ones.

Comment: @TheFrustratedProgrammer a look at your code would be nice. As it is, your setup doesn't sound very secure to me, especially the part where you send sensitive data to Notepad. Anyone interested in your data could just pull the text out of Notepad without even needing to bother with your message.

Comment: @computerfreaker , the notepad scenario is only an example to simplify my problem, i would send the strings to another application but i would still be using the SendMessage to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is not secure; there are multiple ways a `SendMessage` call can be spied on by anyone who wants to do so.

[`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) with `WH_CALLWNDPROC` or `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET` will let an attacker monitor all messages being sent to a given thread, or they can monitor all messages across the system and just filter out the ones headed to your `SendMessage` target.

Alternately, an attacker can inject themselves into your recipient process, using [`WriteProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to write a DLL name into the recipient process, then [`CreateRemoteThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to load the DLL into the target process. After that, monitoring the process's messages should be fairly trivial.

To avoid using a DLL, an attacker could also use [`WriteProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to write code directly into the target process's memory space, then [`CreateRemoteThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to call it.

All three of these monitoring methods are documented [in this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces). It's admittedly a little old, but the methods should still be relevant, particularly the `SetWindowsHookEx` one.

An attacker could also [hook various Windows APIs directly](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed); it's difficult and somewhat risky, but depending on the sensitivity of your data an attacker might find it a worthwhile approach.

Trying to protect your data will be very difficult, honestly. You can look at how [KeePass](http://keepass.info/download.html) keeps passwords secure; it's got a setting (at least in the 1.x branch; KeePass 2.x is an entirely different app) to "allow pasting only once and protect against clipboard spies", which might be of some benefit to you. Taking another cue from KeePass, you can also look into Windows' [Data Protection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx).

As a side note, you may want to replace

```
SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, TextBox1.Text);
```

with

```
SendMessage(child, WM_SETTEXT, 0, TextBox1.Text);
```

for readability. Not many people will recognize 0x000C by itself, although it's possible to guess what the message is based on context.